# How does for (x : y) { ... } work?

Tags: java, for-loop

[I have seen this kind of for-loop around](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach1) but I don't quite understand it. Can someone explain how it works?

Example from the link:

```
public static void printPersonsWithinAgeRange(
    List<Person> roster, int low, int high) {
    for (Person p : roster) {
        if (low <= p.getAge() && p.getAge() < high) {
            p.printPerson();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** question already answered here: [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work).

**EDIT 2:** Oracle tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: it is a shortcut for iterator. It will give you a referennce to the next element in the list at every loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work

Comment: It is known as the [*Enhanced for-loop*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). Oracle recommends *"using this form of the for statement instead of the general form whenever possible."*

Comment: Thanks , @Mr.Polywhirl This is what I was looking for, adding to original post.